# How can I use jQuery to get an HtmlTableRow (which starts life invisible/hidden) to display?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I am creating some html elements via server-side (C#) code. Since this is a jQuery forum, I won't show that code, but it adds a column caption row and a first row of "textboxes" that are visible; then, I add two more rows of textboxes that start off invisible. I additionally (no pun intended) have a button (with the caption "+") that should make the first invisible row visible on the first click, and the second invisible row visible on the second click. I'm trying to accomplish that with this jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnAddFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    if ($('[id$=foapalrow3]').not(":visible")) {
        console.log('reached the foapalrow3 not visible branch');
        //        $('[id$=foapalrow3]').slideDown(); <= neither this nor the below works
        $('[id$=foapalrow3]').attr("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else if ($('[id$=foapalrow4]').not(":visible")) {
        console.log('reached the foapalrow4 not visible branch');
        $('[id$=foapalrow4]').slideDown();
    }
});
```

I do see the "reached the foapalrow3 not visible branch'" log msg in the console, but neither the slideDown() nor the "visibility=visible" code does a durned thing (pardon my 1800s backwoods dialect).

What do I need to do to visiblize foaplarow3 (and 4, as appropriate)?

Here's the code-behind/server-side (C#):

```
foapalrow3 = new HtmlTableRow();
foapalrow3.ID = "foapalrow3";

var cellColIndex2 = new HtmlTableCell();
cellColIndex2.Width = CELL_WIDTH;
foapalrow3.Cells.Add(cellColIndex2);
var cellColFund2 = new HtmlTableCell();
cellColFund2.Width = CELL_WIDTH;
foapalrow3.Cells.Add(cellColFund2);
var cellColOrg2 = new HtmlTableCell();
cellColOrg2.Width = CELL_WIDTH;
foapalrow3.Cells.Add(cellColOrg2);
var cellColAccount2 = new HtmlTableCell();
cellColAccount2.Width = CELL_WIDTH;
foapalrow3.Cells.Add(cellColAccount2);
var cellColActivity2 = new HtmlTableCell();
cellColActivity2.Width = CELL_WIDTH;
foapalrow3.Cells.Add(cellColActivity2);
var cellColAmount2 = new HtmlTableCell();
cellColAmount2.Width = CELL_WIDTH;
foapalrow3.Cells.Add(cellColAmount2);

boxIndex2 = new TextBox()
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH
};
cellColIndex2.Controls.Add(boxIndex2);
boxFund2 = new TextBox()
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH
};
cellColFund2.Controls.Add(boxFund2);
boxOrganization2 = new TextBox()
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH
};
cellColOrg2.Controls.Add(boxOrganization2);
boxAccount2 = new TextBox()
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH
};
cellColAccount2.Controls.Add(boxAccount2);
boxActivity2 = new TextBox()
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH
};
cellColActivity2.Controls.Add(boxActivity2);
boxAmount2 = new TextBox()
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH
};
cellColAmount2.Controls.Add(boxAmount2);
foapalHTMLTable.Rows.Add(foapalrow3);
foapalrow3.Visible = false;
```

The code for foapalrow4 is the same as the above for foapalrow3, except for the obvious differences. So, basically, all I need to happen on the clicking of the "+" button is to set:

```
foapalrow3.Visible = false;
```

...but via jQuery. And this is what it looks like:

[image]

### UPDATE

I looked at the generated HTML for the page, and was surprised by a couple of things: one, the jQuery appears in there twice (it's duplicated) - why?

Second, and perhaps more significantly, there is no "foapalrow3" anywhere in the source, although that is the ID I give the HtmlTableRow. No wonder it's not being responded to, if it isn't aware of the existence of an element whose ID ends with "foapalrow3". The button's ID is there:

```
<h2>Section 5: FOAPAL / Payment Amount Information</h2></span><br></br><button id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_btnAddFoapalRow" type="button" OnClientClick="return false;">+</button><table border="2">
```

...and thus its click event is handled, but why isn't the ID for the HtmlTableRow not recorded, and what do I have to do so that it is?

### UPDATE 2

Here is the HTML for "Section 5" which is where the rows should appear:

```
<span class="finaff-webform-field-label" style="display:inline-block;">Explain Payment: </span><textarea name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$explainPaymentTextBox" rows="2" cols="20" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_explainPaymentTextBox" class="finaff-webform-field-input" style="width:660px;display:inline-block;"></textarea><br></br><span class="finaff-webform-field-label"><h2>Section 5: FOAPAL / Payment Amount Information</h2></span><br></br><button id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_btnAddFoapalRow" type="button" OnClientClick="return false;">+</button><table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="finaff-webform-field-label">Index</span></td>
        <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="finaff-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Fund</span></td>
        <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="finaff-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Organization</span></td>
        <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="finaff-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Account</span></td>
        <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="finaff-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Activity</span></td>
        <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="finaff-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Amount</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="88px"><input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl130" type="text" class="finaff-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" /></td>
        <td width="88px"><input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl132" type="text" class="finaff-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" /></td>
        <td width="88px"><input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl134" type="text" class="finaff-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" /></td>
        <td width="88px"><input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl136" type="text" class="finaff-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" /></td>
        <td width="88px"><input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl138" type="text" class="finaff-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" /></td>
        <td width="88px"><input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl140" type="text" class="finaff-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It seems to me that the creation of the HtmlTableRow is not being fully "translated" to the generated html for some reason.

### UPDATE 3

I tried adding IDs to the Textboxes, too, like so:

```
boxIndex2 = new TextBox()
{
    CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input",
    Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH,
    ID = "boxIndex2foapalrow3"
};
cellColIndex2.Controls.Add(boxIndex2);
```

...but searching the generated HTML ("View Source") for "boxIndex2foapalrow3" turns up not even a turnip.

I can understand why the "right" elements need to ID'd for this to work, but why do the IDs not even show up in the generated HTML?

What we've got here (in addition to the everlasting failure to communicate) is TextBoxes added to HtmlTableCells, which are added to HtmlTableRows, which are added to an HtmlTable. It is the HtmlTableRow that I'm setting invisible in the C# code-behind:

```
foapalrow3.Visible = false;
```

...but it seems like setting it back to visible is a conundrum wrapped in an enigma wrapped in a mystery, etc.

Maybe the cells need IDs too, like:

```
cellColAmount2.ID = "cellAmount2foapalrow3";
```

?

### UPDATE 4

I reckon it should have been obvious - when the elements are not visible, they are not rendered on the page, and thus they are not found in the "View Source" and thus they are not found when searching for an ID that ends with "foapalrow3".

So I still don't know *how* to do what I want, but I know why my present (now former, actually) approach hung fire.

Perhaps rather than making them invisible, I'll have to give them a height the equivalent of the combined IQ of the members of the Flat Earth Society (0).

### UPDATE 5

I tried using height to get it to work, by changing the HtmlTableRow's Height val to zilch in the code-behind:

```
foapalrow3.Height = "0";
```

...but that did not work, either, because setting the height to zero did nothing - the row displays at full/normal height...

### UPDATE 6

Riffing on David Waters' answer, I tried this:

Code-behind:

```
foapalrow3.Attributes.Add("display", "none");
foapalHTMLTable.Rows.Add(foapalrow3);
//foapalrow3.Visible = false;
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnAddFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    if ($('[id$=foapalrow3]').not(":visible")) {
        console.log('reached the foapalrow3 not visible branch');
        $('[id$=foapalrow3]').attr("display", "table-row");
    }
    else if ($('[id$=foapalrow4]').not(":visible")) {
        console.log('reached the foapalrow4 not visible branch');
        $('[id$=foapalrow4]').slideDown();
    }
});
```

...but no go. The HtmlTableRow is still visible from the git-go.

### UPDATE 7

I added this to the code-behind:

```
foapalrow3.Attributes["class"] = "hiddenTableRow";
foapalHTMLTable.Rows.Add(foapalrow3);
```

...and this to the script file:

```
<style>
.hiddenTableRow {
   display:none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* This is supposed to make the rows visible, but is not yet working... */
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnAddFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    $("[id$=foapalrow3]").removeClass("hiddenTableRow");
    if ($('[id$=foapalrow3]').not(":visible")) {
        $('[id$=foapalrow3]').attr("display", "table-row");
    }
    else if ($('[id$=foapalrow4]').not(":visible")) {
        console.log('reached the foapalrow4 not visible branch');
        $('[id$=foapalrow4]').slideDown();
    }
});

</script>
```

...but foapalrow3 is *still* visible from the git-go; yet, clicking the button *does* add the next (third blank row, which is foapalrow4) so, we're on the right track, but something is still phunky in funky town.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code that the C# code generates. It's not really important how it is generated but what the result is.

Comment: Still haven't added the whole HTML. But it seems to be a C# issue anyway.

Comment: We need to see the generated html.

Comment: Okay, I added the pertinent generated html to Update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `foapalrow3.Visible = false;` from the server side code, as this will prevent html being generated for this row
2. Add a class or style to foapalrow3 applying the CSS property `display:none;`
3. On you button click either remove the class from foapalrow3 or if you choose to use a style attribute change `display` to `display:table-row;`

e.g.

CSS

```
.hiddenTableRow {
   display:none;
}
```

.Net

```
// foapalrow3.Visible = false;
// Edit - CssClass is not present on HtmlTableRow
// foapalrow3.CssClass = "hiddenTableRow";
foapalrow3.Attributes["class"] = "hiddenTableRow";
```

Javascript

```
$("[Css Selector To find the Row]").removeClass("hiddenTableRow");
```

Comment: foapalrow3.CssClass = "hiddenTableRow" won't compile; there is no "CssClass" available to me...

Comment: Sorry did not test my code, try again with `.Attributes["class"] = "...";`

Comment: Look at the source of the html page, see which row got the style added, see what styles are applied to the row you want invisible. Work from there.